# $\infty$-operads and $E_\infty$-algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

I work in algebraic geometry. Lately, the answer to most of my questions seems to be "you should read Lurie's *Higher Algebra*."  I took this advice seriously, however it turned out not to be an easy task.

From what I gather, I should learn how to work with $E_\infty$-rings. I understand the definition of a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category as a certain coCartesian fibration $p\colon C^\otimes \to N({\rm Fin}_*)$, and that an $E_\infty$-ring in a stable symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $C$ should be a certain section of $p$.

In *Higher Algebra*, $E_\infty$-algebras are a special case of algebras over $\infty$-operads, where the operad ${\rm Comm}$ is just the identity $N({\rm Fin}_*)\to N({\rm Fin}_*)$. Lurie treats general $\infty$-operads in detail in two chapters of about 150 pages each, and in later chapters he specializes to the case of the operads $E_k$. Since I seem to be interested in the final operad ${\rm Comm}$ only, it is difficult for me to motivate myself to read through the chapters about the general theory of $\infty$-operads.

> **Question.** As an algebraic geometer interested in making the step from commutative rings to $E_\infty$-rings, should I care about $E_k$-rings for $k<\infty$, or algebras over more general $\infty$-operads? If so, why?

Comment: If you're interested in derived Azumaya algebras or things like that you need associative algebras (i.e. algebras over the $E_1$-operad), and modules over an algebra are defined via another ∞-operad with two colors. That said you don't need to read *all* of the 150 pages.

Comment: But how do I know what I don't need to know?

Comment: Well, I suggest you work backwards from what you want to know. That's what I did back when I started learning the stuff. Let's say you start with sections 2.1 and 2.2 of Higher Algebra skipping the proofs but trying to understand the definitions.

Comment: There's an earlier incarnation of this material that discusses only commutative and associative algebras; see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703204 (go to the first paper in the version history) and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702299. You might find that more readable. (This won't simplify the definition of commutative algebra, but will be a much shorter account which doesn't muck about with general operads.)

Comment: Thank you both for the reading suggestions. I think a (slightly implicit) part of my question still stands: in what ways can $E_k$ algebras with $1<k<\infty$ be useful to an algebraic geometer?

Comment: A related question: in what ways are non-comm. rings ($E_1$-algs) useful to an algebraic geometer? While there are places that non-comm rings appear (Brauer groups come to mind) an argument can be made that the field of non-comm rings is mostly concerned with things disjoint from the concerns of algebraic geometry. The $E_k$-operads interpolate between assoc ($E_1$) to "comm" ($E_\infty$), so you should expect a similar relationship. There are places where they show up (analogs of Brauer groups, the Deligne conjecture, deformations, etc), but mostly they are separate from the core concerns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two examples where $E_k$-algebras show up in algebraic geometry, for $1<k<\infty$ (actually, just $k=2$):

- The work of Gaitsgory and Lurie on Weil's conjecture for function fields. See [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/tamagawa.pdf), [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/tamagawa-abridged.pdf), and [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/282y.html), especially Lectures 21-24. As far as I understand it, the rough idea is that you want to prove a version of the Grothendieck-Lefschetz trace formula, but for a non-constructible sheaf on a certain poorly behaved algebraic prestack (the Ran space). They seem to circumvent this by developing some version of Verdier duality in this setting, that can be viewed as an algebro-geometric version of Koszul duality for $E_2$-algebras. I am not sure if the theory of $E_2$-algebras is strictly necessary for the proof, or just provides motivation.
- The work of Toën and Vezzosi on Bloch's conductor conjecture, see [arXiv:1605.08941](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08941) and [arXiv:1710.05902](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05902). A main ingredient in their strategy is also a trace formula, but in the noncommutative setting (smooth proper dg-categories).  It turns out that the dg-category $T$ they want to apply this to is not actually proper over the base.  However, there exists a certain $E_2$-algebra $B$ over the base and $T$ turns out to be $B$-linear and proper as a $B$-linear dg-category.  The trace formula they prove turns out to extend to the $E_2$-setting as well.

Regarding the comment about $E_1$-algebras: The derived category of a variety is equivalent to the derived category of modules over a certain $E_1$-algebra (the endomorphism algebra of the compact generator). A pretty active area of research in algebraic geometry is noncommutative algebraic geometry (via derived/dg-categories) and its relationship to birational geometry. See work of Bondal, Orlov, Kuznetsov, Bridgeland, Huybrechts, Van den Bergh, etc.

Edit: Here's another example.

- Arinkin-Gaitsgory, *Singular support on coherent sheaves and the Geometric Langlands conjecture*, Selecta 2015. They develop the theory of singular support in the setting of (ind)-coherent sheaves, on pretty general objects (derived Artin stacks), and use this to give a precise formulation of the categorical geometric Langlands conjecture. To that end they revisit some of the work of Benson-Iyengar-Krause on supports in triangulated categories. It seems that the correct setting for this theory turns out to be a dg-category/stable infinity-category equipped with an action of some $E_2$-algebra.